# Convert a dynamic json object into generics type in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want the following json object to convert into the equivalent generic type in typescript.

This json object has dynamic keys for example `applications` and `permissions` can have dynamic keys. The immediate keys inside applications for example `application_management`, `user_management` can be dynamic and also inside `permissions`, `create_application`, `delete_application`, `update_application` and so on can be dynamic as well.

I have tried to do it using interface but didn't able to do it. Could you please help me solve this?

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "isSuperAdmin": true,
            "firstName": "Oleksii",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "alexp@point2web.com",
            "gender": null,
            "dob": null,
            "photo": null,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "slug": "Head of Department-(Account Management-Network-P2W North America)"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "slug": "Team Lead-(Account Management-Network-P2W North America)"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "slug": "Employee-(Account Management-Network-P2W North America)"
                }
            ],
            "applications": {
                "application_management": {
                    "id": 41,
                    "slug": "application_management",
                    "appName": "Application Management",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "appType": "CODED",
                    "appUrl": "application-management",
                    "appIcon": "http://api.chromosome-studio.com/uploads/applications/application.png",
                    "permissions": {
                        "delete_application": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "action": "Delete Application",
                            "slug": "delete_application",
                            "level": "all"
                        },
                        "update_application": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "action": "Update Application",
                            "slug": "update_application",
                            "level": "all"
                        },
                        "create_application": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "action": "Create Application",
                            "slug": "create_application",
                            "level": "all"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "user_management": {
                    "id": 42,
                    "slug": "user_management",
                    "appName": "Application Management",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "appType": "CODED",
                    "appUrl": "user-management",
                    "appIcon": "http://api.chromosome-studio.com/uploads/applications/users.png",
                    "permissions": {
                        "create_application": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "action": "Create Application",
                            "slug": "create_application",
                            "level": "all"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

HO, another Romain was faster.
But i have a little different solution

```
type Role = { id: number; slug: string };
type ObjectStatus = 'ACTIVE' | 'INACTIVE'; // add other status
type AppType = 'CODED' | 'DYNAMIC';
type PermissionLevel = 'all' | 'admin' | 'guest'; // add other levels

type ApplicationsType = 'user' | 'application';
type CrudTypes = 'delete' | 'update' | 'create';
type PermissionKeys = `${CrudTypes}_application`;

type Permission<NAME extends ApplicationsType, CRUD extends CrudTypes = CrudTypes> = {
    id: number;
    action: `${Capitalize<CRUD>} ${Capitalize<NAME>}`;
    slug: `${CRUD}_${NAME}`;
    level: PermissionLevel;
};

type Application<NAME extends ApplicationsType> = {
    id: number;
    slug: `${NAME}_management`;
    appName: `${Capitalize<NAME>} Management`;
    status: ObjectStatus;
    appType: AppType;
    appUrl: `${NAME}-management`;
    permissions: { [key in PermissionKeys]?: Permission<NAME> };

    [key: string]: unknown;
};

type ApplicationList = { [key in ApplicationsType as `${key}_management`]?: Application<key> };

type User = {
    id: 1;
    isSuperAdmin: true;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    gender: string | null;
    dob: string | null;
    photo: string | null;
    status: ObjectStatus;
    roles: Array<Role>;
    applications: ApplicationList;
};
```

When appliying this type to your input, i get compilation errors on

- application.user_management.appName which is awaited to be 'User Management'
- application.user_management.permission.create_application.action which is awaited to be 'Create User'
- application.user_management.permission.create_application.slug which is awaited to be 'create_user'

---

A little update to better type permission list because this leads to not perfect typing .

```
type PermissionList<NAME extends ApplicationsType> = { [key in CrudTypes as `${key}_${NAME}`]?: Permission<NAME, key> };
```

then replace in Application :

```
permissions: PermissionList<NAME>;
```

That fire one more error on

- application.user_management.permission.create_application which is now awaited to be 'create_user', and allow only 'Create' as crud action.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBASgewDawLwwN4wJYBMBcMAdgK4C2ARlAE4DcMAzkiQOaEMjXZEswC%20tUJFgB5CgCsoAYxABlEAEMQJBjHQByAIIBhACoBJAGoBRdTAA%20MdfoByOgyfX0A9M5gLcuGAhAALGoyKygxC0DCaEBC6wmpW2iIAIsYJZpbqCQCadgCy%20tpOobAACjRk2AwM2AhEADJQAG5QSLHqCkhIqVYeZUSd6iwkUBxOMK7uFd5%20ASiNSCGF4ZFI2FJKVUQM0WEaKjR9Cksra9UF4GHa1CS4W0MtuE1QIFB9JBC4Ss8WVlLUUB%20nMRK1DKFXWAGkoGBVOgAAYAEgwFyuNwYfAA%20gcIMtViB1jDBAsgSDKtUADw5YwwKAADyeRFwqgiWKOuOqm2EABoYNo4ABVBJU2lQemqJHXYTQ7mXcXQBgAPliGGAMBVOAIxHIVDoytVChk60I8MRB2wimWAC8oKSefy5XwYAjtCazdhLeTNNljHb8TqVUxWIbHXyEuiERS%20D7VTAZk1CETyiTag0moIBMBCaUE%20sauUQO7PYK6QzFsycet2dAFegsABtADWkJwRClyIl4xgRobYFDGHDMIAugB%20OOZ0FkilcrsKtMLJnY45EfOUmlFxmHMtsm5VzC%20tWEUiUGiCKP%20tgdsMe4zosgKIgKFhQMjCkCR3WRGwKJ%20B40QU1tV1WhSdowNkt73o%20z6vn6QQqIQYiSDI8hKCox5vlEwiEEyNyoSqmK8tQSDfuGAC0N53g%20T5EC%20OEwNAwJZmyI70WOtS5kucoElG9aQuwnDcCw-aECQRB1kQCAAO5EKmBJnLAc4stmuaKjA3FgE2JbzqyGw3O2naQteYEUZBQ6YeuC6klO-AyTEvIMAE1a7nghAAIw0eUsivDQmi4D0hCcIMNEAGbYNQHAfl%20gRcDwNFIAoYWflAvFRSwNGPgo2CEZF-E0Q%209I0El-FfKQ7Q0bgCAUAVPBFSQJW7hAvg%20AglW8JYxVIDRHDIQwcESNIcgwQwNHUMgQyYdQ1AKGApKICgHG7pimnlqZpYLjmHDSemUhsiA3hEFAtn5TAB3UIqjnqs5HKOQwHl0d5vkwP5UCXVGwWhSA4WJVYIgoHWlTYOoz2qrF8UReoAO7mlGWEK0KDUhAAACEAINwIAAEziVAFAAHRbWQ4NRrl9zUPuNVIIDKplRVGrtOTtENSATXU2Tu6dcE0P2EYpi08NKDdSpu5RkqUbC6qTkwBdAsi4wzBnuoAASfxeAggUwAkUAQAo1AgJRIDEQAFJoUhbcJO2geREFUcRNiPOJCDUHWxFFKjADqMA2HbfjhE%20XCrAAlOoksqnwtOC4Hwti6jIdS6e0O6H8ZAwHUHj64bxtUSBhkW7r1sgLb9uOy7bse74Xs0Ec-th8HYdC1LUZiwAzFHIsx1YxhkFiCBgFAUAp0bCAmxn5s61bNt2w7Tuu%207Wsl5o3vlwHtd8Lu-a0wtCmMTutdrxuRBomR4E64QNe1yqYsACwSyfqot60ZlaXvmc6-jV-uO%20CXs3f6yDwfz7P1frOwSsBzRwTdhaYhuNDeISQUigKjHhAi0Nt4LlIo-X%20sC0L6C2kQaGvgQAgAgPgVwJoca%20GGmQBADAEBPmIhwK4VQcZUOcK8JACAPAMGcEgrS7DOHrCxhAHgf8T50WJEtTeL8oz3BQE8DEn9qhHzDuIhu6Cr56i0tDNWUi5KyN6Mok%20N9JGPCgDIlaWlBHiKjDGTKMMOgKKllXcxqpXjvGkTwuRYiHF13VJHWxKj9RuPULyN4HwNLrx0T4vRMtoZOI%20MYxaJxdG10sYg9oC8PH2I8T8P4LjtHyI8eHc6CSpaqINHEX4wT5I7zMR4m%20mSYmuLCXkixyYrFtBsXkpe4iOl2NAbsagD8h7PlyS-c%203jxE316f0n%20VEqki0xB9aGx1v5GWmVyMY4k4pAO0UsrOMzhYAL5loPQnNdlwMiBAuIiRkgnLQvhKxvSUEDJWeEzEmD-G4PwYQjhv4SFkIoVQnutDcD0NxkwjubCvkmPLEwuyoU%20ECN0cIhiGwhkONqdI3pKLGlrI2Wiox9TMV5PPoU2ZfjsGlKybAY6ANRhuHWaodQFwKUhMqcSvZkTvhlPRTC6l2L6W4tiaE65V8kldBSeEqMXSr6SuFtKpeaYgA)

Answer (score 1):

here is a type for your object :

```
    type TypeForJsonObject = {
        id: number;
        isSuperAdmin: boolean;
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        email: string;
        gender: string | null;
        dob: string | null;
        photo: string | null;
        status: "ACTIVE";
        roles: {
            id: number;
            slug: string;
        }[];
        applications: Record<string, {
            id: number;
            slug: string;
            appName: string;
            status: "ACTIVE";
            appType: "CODED";
            appUrl: string;
            appIcon: string;
            permissions: Record<string, {
                id: number;
                action: string;
                slug: string;
                level: "all";
            }>;
        }>
    };
```

What you ask for is the Record<KeyType,ValueType> wich allow you to have "dynamic" properties of given Type (here string keys for complex typed values.